# How can I fix biopython urllib.error.HTTPError 502?

Tags: runtime-error, urllib, python-3.4, biopython

Hi I am using biopython to pull files from NCBI using Entrez. The program works on small files but on larger files I get an error. I would really appreciate some insight or help figuring out what went wrong.

Here is the program:

```py
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "jbro262@lsu.edu"
search_handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide",term="Saimiri",usehistory="n")
search_results = Entrez.read(search_handle)
search_handle.close()

gi_list = search_results["IdList"]
count = int(search_results["Count"])
a = open("Numfile.txt", "a+")
a.write("The number of Saimiri files are :")
a.write(str(count))
a.write("\n")
a.close()

webenv = search_results["WebEnv"]
query_key = search_results["QueryKey"]

batch_size = 25
out_handle = open("SaimiriDNA.fasta", "w")

for start in range(0,count,batch_size):

    end = min(count, start+batch_size)
    print("Going to download record %i to %i" % (start+1, end))

    fetch_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", rettype="fasta", retmode="text", retstart=start, retmax=batch_size, webenv=webenv, query_key=query_key)
    data=fetch_handle.read()
    fetch_handle.close()
    out_handle.write(data)
out_handle.close()
```

Here are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Entrezfiles_Saimiri.py", line 53, in <module>
    fetch_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", rettype="fasta", retmode="text", retstart=start, retmax=batch_size, webenv=webenv, query_key=query_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/

dist-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 149, in efetch
    return _open(cgi, variables, post)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 464, in _open
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Bio/Entrez/__init__.py", line 462, in _open
    handle = _urlopen(cgi)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 461, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 571, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 499, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 579, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
```

Does this mean something is going wrong with my server while the files are downloading?

Comment: Are you sure that ```biopython``` may works with python3.4? See https://github.com/biopython/biopython On this page they are recommend python 2.7

Comment: Yes it works. I've used it on my laptop using the same program for smaller files and it worked fine. I also tested on my linus box and it works fine. It's just when I try to download larger files.

Comment: May be something with your db-server? Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in which the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the request

Comment: This is the NCBI failing. The 502 is a typical error when you request to a server like nginx that is configured as a proxy to some backend machines, but the backend machines are unable to provide a valid response (machines too busy or something like that).

Comment: Okay. Should I just try to run the program again and see if I get the same error? How can I fix this issue with the NCBI database?